# Run and build Visual Studio project on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, xcode

Can I open a Visual Studio C++ project on Mac OS X and run the app?

Answer (score 1):

Although you will get more info from Windows/Mac developers on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), I can tell you that depending upon the project and its dependencies, you might get away with it or you may not. Of course nothing Windows related can be run on OSX, so if you're only doing a "hello world", chances are you will be able to run it, provided you have the right toolchain to build that (gcc++, etc.)

Regarding whether there's a "Visual Studio Compatible IDE" the answer is "no" (unless you consider MonoDevelop which works 'ok' for some things).

The solution, of course, is to use one of the virtualization alternatives ([Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/), [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/)) or simply have a windows partition via Bootcamp.

Comment: You won't get away with it at all - the code might run but it needs a recompile - the format of an executable differs and the libraries needed differ as well

Comment: I've also had success with the [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)--a freely available virtualization application.

Comment: +1 for Virtual Box. @Mark of course, but if you're making a simple C++ app you can easily get away and recompile that. It's obvious that you need to recompile for your new architecture/OS. But the question is really vague if you ask me. ;)

Comment: @MartínMarconcini - my reading of the question is that it is NOT obvious to the OP